# Uploading Files/Attachments via the API v7 (Self-Hosted)

Tags: activecollab

I contacted ActiveCollab support, who instructed me to create a post here.

We are running version 7.3.306 and need to upload a file/attachment via the API.

I have been referencing the [API Documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/tasks/attachments.html), which instructs me to do a POST to `/upload-files`, then use the "code" from the response to attach it to a task in a subsequent POST to `/projects/<PROJECT ID>/tasks`.

I've tried the curl request below, which returns a HTTP 200 with a body of `[]` instead of the expected response shown in the documentation.

```bash
curl --location 'https://<URL OF SELF HOSTED VERSION>/api/v7/upload-files' \
--header 'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: <WORKING TOKEN>' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/png' \
--data '@/path/to/test/png-test.png'
```

Thoughts on what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the content type. Instead of sending the file as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the POST request, it needed to submitted as `multipart/form-data`.

```bash
curl --location 'https://<URL OF SELF HOSTED VERSION>/api/v7/upload-files' \
--header 'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: <WORKING TOKEN>' \
--form 'file=@"/path/to/test/png-test.png"'
```

The curl command above returns JSON which contains a code for the file, which can be used to attach the file to a task:

```bash
curl --location 'https://<URL OF SELF HOSTED VERSION>/api/v7/projects/<PROJECT ID>/tasks' \
--header 'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: <WORKING TOKEN>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "task_list_id": <TASK LIST ID>,
    "project_id": <PROJECT ID>,
    "name": "<NAME OF TASK>",
    "body": "<BODY OF TASK>",
    "attach_uploaded_files": [
        "<UPLOADED FILE CODE>"
    ]
}'
```

Further reading on [ReqBin](https://reqbin.com/req/c-sma2qrvp/curl-post-form-example) explains the differences between the content types and appropriate curl syntax if you're interested.